# Cassiopeia Sleeper Train Japan - Tours?

Tags: trains, tickets, japan, japan-rail

The [Cassiopeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassiopeia_(train)) sleeper train between Ueno and Sapporo was discontinued a while ago and we didn't get around to use it while it was still running.

However, the Wikipedia site linked to a feature that mentioned could [re-open as a cruise train](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219094900/http://ajw.asahi.com/article/behind_news/social_affairs/AJ201602190048#). I also saw a NHK feature once that showed that it running as a packaged tour by a private operator (albeit only as far as Aomori).

Question: Does anyone know whether this train is still used for tours, and if so how one would go about to make a booking? I didn't find anything online, at least not in English language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, The Cassiopeia is still used for tour excursion service from Tokyo. Tours are typically start a minimum of 100 000yen. See the below website (Japanese) for details and tours can be booked from the same website though keep in mind these tours tend to get booked up really quickly

https://www.club-t.com/spgroup/special/japan/cassiopeia/index.htm

and this tour site (thanks @fkraiem)

http://www.v-travels.co.jp/sp/cassiopeia/

Comment: It seems there are several tour companies that use it; club-t leases it from JR East, and JR East runs [its own tours](http://www.v-travels.co.jp/sp/cassiopeia/) as well...

Comment: BTW, the Cassiopeia does not actually run from Osaka or Nagoya; if you book a tour from there, you first take a Shinkansen to Tokyo and a regular train to Ueno.

Comment: Great, thanks :) Is there any hint of "international" booking (as in: English-Language) options, though? I could probably go through a specialized travel agent, ask a friend to translate or use Google Translate as a last resort, but I wondered if international resellers for such tours exist...

Comment: @fkraiem Thanks, should have read the fine print. Edited.

Comment: @averell If you are in Japan, the JR East tours should be all "View Plaza" travel centers in major JR East stations. If you contact them in advance they can arrange English-speaking staff.

Comment: Read, "should be *available at* all View Plaza travel centers".